# normalisation of audio signal and reverting to original matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, steganography

I am doing a project in audio stenography. I need to embed some text in an audio signal(.wav file) . 
So i converted the audio signal ranging from -1 to 1(double) to -32767 to +32767(int16) so i cold embed the data in the LSB of the coefficients.
The problem now is that i don't know how to get the values from int16 to their respective double equivalents.

I have used the following code for normalization:

```
    [y, fs, nBits,opts]=wavread('one.wav');
     y2=y-(min(y));
     y2=y2/max(y2);
     y2=y2* (2^16 - 1) - 2^15;
     y2b=int16(y2);
```

can anyone guide me about the reverse process of this?

Comment: Watch out for when max(y2) is equal to 0 - zerodivide!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to save (and store) the `ymin = min(y)` and `y2max = max(y2)` for the reversal. Then get the double version ofthe int16 and perform the reversal procedure as needed:

```
y3 = double(y2b);
y3 = (y3 + 2^15) / (2^16 - 1);
y3 = y3 * y2max;
y3 = y3 + ymin;
```

Then store y3 to the output file as needed.

Comment: @elomage-I am still not getting the waveform similar to the original one...the value of the first element was 0 and in the waveform obtained after your process the value is -0.5..

Comment: Note, that y2max and ymin are the values that you obtained in your code above. I just did an example run for sample value 0 with -1 as min and +1 as max values of the raw signal, and I get 0 after the reversal.

Answer (score 0):

elomage reversed the normalisation, I don't see any reason to do so because the lsb gets lost.

```
double(x)/intmax(class(x))
```

Comment: could you clarify a bit more on your answer?...I am not getting it

Comment: If you have a signal in the range -32767...32767, you have to divide by 32767 to scale it to -1...1

Comment: so, essentially  i would have to loop over all the values and divide by 32767 to get the double value right?

Comment: You don't need a loop, x can be a vector.

Comment: This is a neat trick. However, what you get after Daniel's is a normailzed signal, not the original one, as imperfect or shifted it might be.

Comment: i am still not getting the original signal. I tried both the methods described above. Please advise.

Comment: @AneeshK: If you are expecting the original signal, why do you appply a normalisation in the first step?

Comment: i am applying the normalization in order to perform stenography.

Comment: I don't see any reason to use a normalisation before adding a stenography.